# How to load xml into flash via php?

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, drupal, flash

I have a problem and couldn't find an answer, so sorry if this is posted before.

I have 2 SWF files for a crossword puzzle: first one is for creating puzzles and outputting XML files upon clicking the "Save" button and second SWF is displaying those puzzles to the users by listing and loading those XML files and upon clicking it loads the selected XML file into SWF. This is okay so far here. But I need to use web interface so that a user inside a website sees those XML list  on the web page and upon clicking/selecting, the second SWF will load with the related XML file. I need this because I will organize those XML files with some modules inside drupal such as Organic Groups. So each user will see different lists of XML files. For example, I have 2 groups created with my organic groups module inside drupal, each group has a different editor. So those editors will create puzzles and will set them for their groups with Organic groups module
Any idea ? Thanks for advance,

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. It is hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: I have editied the post and tried to give some more details. I dunno it seems clear, but I may be more clear if you say what you didn't understand.

Comment: hmm. It seems like your question is.. "But I need to use web interface so that a user inside a website sees those XML list on the web page and upon clicking/selecting, the second SWF will load with the related XML file.". What have you already tried? How are the XML files stored in drupal?

Comment: nothing really. I just tried to save some information into the databagse. Now after creating each xml, it will also saves id, date, name of the xml into db.. But this is made by manually so I dunno how to connect these with drupal core. I m new to drupal so a bit lost. Any idea is appreciated. Sorry for my bad eng btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed the issue. Created a custom node--puzzle.tpl.php for my puzzleplay.swf file. This custom node template takes the URL of the xml file that attached to "field_xml" field inside "puzzle" node-type. Then, this url is send to AS3 with Flashvars so that eachtime there is a node with a xml file attached to field_xml, puzzleplay.swf loads that specific xml from the url sent with Flashvars.

node--puzzle.tpl.php:

```
 <?php
    $xmlpath = file_create_url($node->field_xml['und']['0']['uri']);
    ?>
    <object 
    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="xmlPath= <?php echo $xmlpath; ?>" />
    <param name="movie" value="/path/to/puzzleplay.swf" />
    <embed allowScriptAccess="always" flashvars="xmlPath=<?php echo $xmlpath; ?>"src="/path/to/puzzleplay.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ></embed>
</object>
```

AS3 Code:

```
var XML_URL:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.xmlPath;
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to drupal but after some research I think I figured a possible and reasonable way to achieve this with a help of a friend. So, to wrap up things so far;

- I have a puzzle maker swf and a puzzle player swf.
- Puzzle maker actually generates some xml files that could be played by Puzzle player(swf).
- These xml files are to be stored in Drupal.
- The stored xml files behaviour is same as Organic groups behaviour. Where the files belonging to a particular group is accessible to the group members.

So the idea of implementation is here,

1.) A custom page for creating puzzle using Puzzle maker(swf). A "Puzzle Data" content-type to hold the xml files. This node is under organic groups.

2.) The editors creates puzzle (things okay so far here) and the xml file will be downloaded to editor's computer.

3.) Now the editor may upload the xml file and attach it to "Puzzle Data" node.

4.) Now I may create a view to display all the "Puzzle Data" nodes in a Organic Group with Views module.

5.) Now comes the tricky part. The actual node display should be a Puzzle Player(swf) that uses the "xml" file uploaded to the node.

After some research I may achieve this either Creating a custom node template or creating a custom field formatter. So here I need abit help  with the php codes so that I may create a field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php I made some research and couldn't find a well detailed example that fits my problem.

(Btw this 2 step: downloading xml and later uploading it to a node is something unwanted, maybe puzzle maker(swf) can be embedded inside node/add path for Puzzle Data content type and editors may download xml so will upload it again into the field on the same page. 
)